# json object contains php DateTime, how to convert to pretty date string

Tags: javascript, json, datetime

So i have a json object, which returned me basically a datetime object, now the question, what is the most efficient way of formatting this to a single string human readable format, in the users (client) local timezone... **In javascript**

```
created: {
   timezone: {
      name: "America/New_York",
      location: {
         country_code: "US",
         latitude: 40.71417,
         longitude: -74.00639,
         comments: "Eastern Time"
      }
   },
   offset: -18000,
   timestamp: 1454125056
},
```

Comment: hehe that one is, let me edit one more correctly, but i still am interested in the most efficient way of doing it.

Comment: What about the offset? I think you're aiming for -03:00 (180 minutes)  but if -18000 is milliseconds then it's -18 seconds.

Comment: No the timezone is EST, so the offset is from php datetime automatically.. the issue is not getting this in PHP but client side local timezoned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the timestamp is an ECMAScript time value (i.e. milliseconds since 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z) then you can give that value directly to a Date object:

```
var d = new Date(1454125056); // 1970-01-17T19:55:25.056Z
```

however it is more likely seconds, so multiply by 1,000:

```
new Date(1454125056*1000).toISOString(); // 2016-01-30T03:37:36.000Z
```

which will create a Date for that moment in time. The offset should probably be ignored, unless it was used in the creation of the time value, in which case it should be added if it follows the ISO convention of negative for west and positive for east. If it follows the ECMAScript convention, the opposite applies.

I'll assume ISO, and since it appears to be seconds, you can apply it to the UTC seconds:

```
var offset = -18000;
d.setUTCSeconds(d.getUTCSeconds() + offset);
console.log(d.toISOString()); // 2016-01-29T22:37:36.000Z
```

Using plain Date methods thereafter will return values based on the host system's timezone settings.

```js
var timeValue = 1454125056;
var offset = -18000;
var d = new Date(timeValue*1000);

document.write(d.toISOString() + '<br>' + d);

d.setUTCSeconds(d.getUTCSeconds() + offset);
document.write('<br>' + d.toISOString() + '<br>' + d);
```

There are many questions here on how to format a date string from a Date object.

Note that javascript is only required consider the daylight saving rules in force at the current time as if they had always existed, so be careful with historical dates.

Comment: Thanks, that toIso string is what i need, but how would i adjust for the clients local timezone?

Comment: Amended the question to indicate that OP wants this in javascript and not PHP also removed the PHP tag. At least future visitors wont get as confused as I did now. You get my UV, hope the OP remembers to accept your answer

Answer (score 1):

Suppose this json object loaded in $created variable. i assume you mean php.

in PHP :

```
$obj  = json_decode($created, true);
$timezone_name = $obj['timezone']['name'];
$timezone_location_country_code = $obj['timezone']['location']['country_code'];
$timezone_location_latitude = $obj['timezone']['location']['latitude'];
$timezone_location_longitude = $obj['timezone']['location']['longitude'];
$timezone_location_comments = $obj['timezone']['location']['comments'];
$offset = $obj['offset'];
$timestamp = date('m/d/Y', abs($obj['timestamp']));
```

in Javascript :

```
getDate: function(timestamp){
// Multiply by 1000 because JS works in milliseconds instead of the UNIX seconds
var date = new Date(timestamp * 1000);

var year = date.getUTCFullYear();
var month = date.getUTCMonth() + 1; // getMonth() is zero-indexed, so we’ll increment to get the correct month number
var day = date.getUTCDate();
var hours = date.getUTCHours();
var minutes = date.getUTCMinutes();
var seconds = date.getUTCSeconds();

month = (month < 10) ? ‘0’ + month : month;
day = (day < 10) ? ‘0’ + day : day;
hours = (hours < 10) ? ‘0’ + hours : hours;
minutes = (minutes < 10) ? ‘0’ + minutes : minutes;
seconds = (seconds < 10) ? ‘0’ + seconds: seconds;

return year + ‘-‘ + month + ‘-‘ + day + ‘ ‘ + hours + ‘:’ + minutes;
}
```

Comment: no i don't need this in php, it already is a datetime object, so no need there, this is client side. Thanks though

Comment: i very much appreciate the addition, that is  another way to do it, but i am lacking the "offset" but i see where you are going with it, thanks! +1 for having both php and javascript